# Display graphs in Neoclipse

Tags: java, neo4j

I am creating unique neo4j nodes in java class based on column values in database.
column value will be  assigned to each node. Code is as follow:

```
public void createNode(String name) {
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("D://NewGraph");
Transaction tx=graphDb.beginTx();       
try{                    
Node nodeName=name;
nodeName = graphDb.createNode();
nodeName.setProperty("name", nodeName);     
tx.success();
}
```

However i am getting an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Node"
How to fix that error? Plz guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in this line

```
       Node nodeName=name;
```

"name" is a string object,which you are assigning  to nodeName of type Node.

Solution:

```
       Node nodeName;
       nodeName.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label(name));
       .....//
```

Comment: I have added above code however getting an error "DynamicLabel cannot be resolved"  which jar file is required for this? Plz guide.

Comment: you should be able to find "DyanmicLabel class" in org.neo4j.graphdb package, which is available in neo4j-kernel jar.